# Not able to scroll the webpage in web view React-native (android)

Tags: react-native, webview

I am using react-native version 0.56
I am also facing the same issue not able to scroll the webpage in webview (android). it works fine in IOS
how to solve this issue?

Comment: Scrolling problem in webview page is not a react-native problem but a webview page problem

Comment: yes I had used webview react-native inbuilt module

Answer (score 0):

Add this package in react native

```
import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';
```

While you render call HTMLView

```
<HTMLView value={this.message} stylesheet={s.TextStyle2}/>
```